# store value of input type="hidden" into a php variable without javascript

Tags: php, javascript

store value of input type="hidden" into a php variable.

The value is set by javascript into a hidden variable[input].

Now i need to save its value into a $myphpvariable.

I cant set the value into session with javascript and cookies is not an option.

Comment: So ask the user to post the form and look at `$_POST`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**After** the page is submitted, hidden input elements will show up in the `$_POST` superglobal, just like any other form element. If the hidden form field were called `coolsecret` then the value would be in `$_POST['coolsecret']` (or `$_GET['coolsecret']` if you used `method=get`).

**Before** the page is submitted, there's no way to get a value from javascript into PHP, because your PHP code is all executed on the server, and the javascript isn't executed until the user has loaded the page on their computer. You should think about what you're trying to accomplish, and whether there's any way to compute the variable you want in PHP instead. If it's absolutely impossible to compute the variable ahead of time, then like Another Code said, you'll need to use something like an AJAX request.

Comment: worked like a charm. used GET .. Thanks big time. Had to change a few things but yr answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by save? When you submit that form you will be having value of hidden variable in `$_POST` or `$_GET` depending on the `method`of `form`

Comment: its magento, there is no form which is posted. If it was that simple i would have done that

Comment: @Umesh251: No form -> No Input tag, No hidden variable. You are having something fundamentally wrong

Comment: sorry its a feildset. no form.

Answer (score 0):

You store php variable in js.but u cant stored js variable into php variable .because php run at server side and javescript at client side

Comment: i know that. Still asked, if there was a kind of doing my thing.

Comment: dont ask such silly question.people are ready to minus any question. like urs.

Answer (score 0):

The only ways to communicate Javascript results to a server-side script are:

- Submit a form to the PHP script
- Perform an asynchronous HTTP request with Javascript's AJAX functionality

You can't just mix the two, since Javascript operates inside the browser and PHP executes before a page is even sent to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Post it to the server then use `$_POST["the_id"]` to get its value.